# What do you call information obtained from an impartial source?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

What do you call information obtained from an independent source (as opposed to official and/or biased sources)? Can I call it, too, independent? Like, "independent data", "independent survey", "independent exit polls", etc. It sounds kind of wrong, but I'm not sure. You *can* say "independent investigation", for instance

Comment: Minor point: in your question title you say, “impartial”, but in the body of your text you say “independent”. Since whatever those are meant to refer to appears to be at the heart of tour question, it might be better to stick to only one of them.

Comment: Are you saying you want a source independent of parties involved in a particular event? The usual adjective here is *non-partisan*, but such sources are still *biased*, sometimes severely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q. What do you call information obtained from an impartial source

I would suggest you would have to call it "**Impartial**" I suppose it could be **"non-aligned"**, though that may have a slightly different connotation. However **the bias of any source and its perceived impartiality is relative.**

I am not an expert in this field but is it not usual to quote the source rather than to try to influence the reader/viewer/receiver of your information, of the validity of your source. Doing so automatically implies that you are biased against the official source. Which, in this case you have already expressed " Quote (as opposed to official and/or biased sources)?" The revelation of the source and it's **perceived impartiality** is also **relative to the bias of the receiver.**

**impartial**: adjective; not supporting any of the sides involved in an argument:

**bias** noun (PREFERENCE) the action of supporting or opposing a particular person or thing in an unfair way, because of allowing personal opinions to influence your judgment:

All REF CED [Impartial](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/impartial)

Comment: 'Based on _____ indicators, the incumbent didn't win in the first round.' Would 'independent' work? What adjectives would fit?

Comment: @Sergey Zolotarev; I am sorry but I am unclear on what you are trying to imply/say. Is it that your "source of the indicators" is not official? In which case just say unofficial source or sources instead of indicators. Or just say preliminary or early indicators suggest that....